# access parent in nested yup validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I have a piece of code and I'm looking to access the parent inside the nested Yup object 'O'. How can I accomplish this?

this is the code:

```
    import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  mode: yup.string().required(),
  quantities: yup
    .object()
    .shape({
      O: yup
        .string()
        .test(
          "is-valid",
          "Validation failed for O based on mode",
          function (value) {
            const mode = this.parent.mode;
            // Access the mode field and perform validation based on its value
            // For example, you can check if mode is 'someMode' and apply specific validation
            return mode === "someMode" ? value > 10 : true;
          }
        ),
      E: yup
        .string()
        .test(
          "is-valid",
          "Validation failed for O based on mode",
          function (value) {
            const mode = this.parent.mode;
            // Access the mode field and perform validation based on its value
            // For example, you can check if mode is 'someMode' and apply specific validation
            return mode === "someMode" ? value > 10 : true;
          }
        ),
      A: yup
        .string()
        .test(
          "is-valid",
          "Validation failed for O based on mode",
          function (value) {
            const mode = this.parent.mode;
            // Access the mode field and perform validation based on its value
            // For example, you can check if mode is 'someMode' and apply specific validation
            return mode === "someMode" ? value > 10 : true;
          }
        ),
      I: yup
        .string()
        .test(
          "is-valid",
          "Validation failed for O based on mode",
          function (value) {
            const mode = this.parent.mode;
            // Access the mode field and perform validation based on its value
            // For example, you can check if mode is 'someMode' and apply specific validation
            return mode === "someMode" ? value > 10 : true;
          }
        ),
      // Other quantity fields
    })
    .test(
      "sum-validation",
      "Sum of quantities must equal 100",
      function (values) {
        const sum = Object.values(values).reduce(
          (acc, value) => acc + parseFloat(value || 0),
          0
        );
        return sum === 100;
      }
    ),
});

const YourForm = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  console.log(errors);
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // Handle form submission
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {/* Use Controller for mode field */}
      <Controller
        name="mode"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field }) => (
          <>
            <input {...field} type="text" placeholder="Mode" />
            {errors?.mode && <p>{errors.mode.message}</p>}
          </>
        )}
      />

      {/* Use Controller for each quantity input */}
      {["I", "E", "A"].map((name) => (
        <div key={name}>
          <Controller
            name={`quantities.${name}`}
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => (
              <>
                <input
                  {...field}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={`Quantity for ${name}`}
                />
                {errors?.quantities?.[name] && (
                  <p>{errors.quantities[name].message}</p>
                )}
              </>
            )}
          />
        </div>
      ))}

      <div key="O">
        <Controller
          name={`quantities.O`}
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({ field }) => (
            <>
              <input {...field} placeholder={`Quantity for 0`} />
              {errors?.quantities?.["O"] && (
                <p>{errors.quantities["O"].message}</p>
              )}
            </>
          )}
        />
      </div>

      {errors?.quantities && <p>{errors.quantities.message}</p>}

      {/* Your other form inputs here */}

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default YourForm;
```

I've attempted various solutions, but none have worked for me. If anyone has encountered this issue before, I would appreciate it if you could share how you resolved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To access the mode field inside the nested quantities object, you should use this.parent.parent.mode.

Try this code:-

```
O: yup
  .string()
  .test(
    "is-valid",
    "Validation failed for O based on mode",
    function (value) {
      const mode = this.parent.parent.mode; // Access the mode field inside the quantities object
      // Your validation logic based on the mode field
      return mode === "someMode" ? value > 10 : true;
    }
  ),
```

Comment: If we log this within the function, we find that there is only one parent; there is no nested parent within the parent

Comment: you may want to check the structure of your data and the way you are defining your schema to ensure that the mode field is indeed a direct sibling of the quantities object.